# Power BI Desktop - Map Visualization Problem (not showing all locations)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In an excel sheet I have several countries listed for different job ID (ex: USA, Canada, UK, UAE, etc). However, once I load the data into power BI and select the map visualization, only one country is listed on the map. How do I get all countries from the spreadsheet be labelled on the map?

Comment: How many items are you trying to map? What does your data model look like?

Answer (score 0):

Maps are a big problem in Power BI.
You should add latitude and longitude columns for every country into your country table.

Answer (score 0):

There are some map specific issue in Power BI which basically belongs to the Map Provider, not a Power BI Issue. For example, in ArcGIS map you have to provide value "United States of America" instead of "USA". Other wise the map will not going to detect that country appropriately.

For your example cases you mentioned USA, Canada, UK, UAE. Here in most case I guess it is related to the country name. Please try with providing full name of countries. You can aslo search Map wise supported country name from their documentation.